# Creating a loop function to calculate cost

Tags: c++, function, loops

Ok so I'm very new to this and I'm trying to create a program that will calculate the cost of any number of long distance calls.  I haven't gotten very far yet, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the function to repeat itself.  Right now I am getting an error saying

> Line 18 a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token and expected ',' or ';' before '{' token.

**Line 18 is the line directly after** `void costCalc(int numCalls)`

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize all variables
       int numCalls = 0;
       int length = 0;
       int hour = 0;
       char day = ' ';
       char dest = ' ';
       double cost = 0.0;

       cout<<"Enter the number of calls: ";
       cin>>numCalls;

       void costCalc(int numCalls)
 {
        if (numCalls > 0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter length of call in minutes: ";
            cin>>length;
            costCalc(numCalls-1);
         }
}

    // Request the number of calls from the user

    // Loop for the requested number of calls:

// Request the user to give you the call length, 
// call day of week and hour of call, and call
// destination

// Instantiate and initialize a Call object 
// using either 
//   a) the 4-parameter constructor, OR 
//   b) the default constructor and each of the 
//      set member functions.

// Get the cost of the call using the calcCallCost
// function and add it to the total cost of the calls.

// Use the callMsg function to print a message about the call  

     // end loop

// Report the total cost of all the calls.

     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a function declared in a function. Move your curly brackets. Also, good use of recursion for an new programmer.

Comment: C does not allow nested functions, as pointed out by @WilliamCustode - move your `costCalc()` function up to above `main()`.

Comment: Is this `C` at all? I haven't seen `using namespace std;` neither `cin` or `cout` inside any `C` source... (correct me if I'm mistaken. I'm `C` newbie too)

Comment: @core1024, you're right.  It's not `C`; it's `C++`.  Streams aren't supported in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the main function before beginning a new one.

You are trying to create a nested function inside main and C or C++ does not support that.

You should merely copy/paste the code of costCalc function before the beginning of main function.

As a side note, a long time ago (1994) gcc (2.95.2) supported nested functions as an extension. But it never came into the C or C++ standard.

I'm not exactly sure why nested functions never got into the standard. It seams simple enough to support (we would probably have to make nested function inline static, but nevertheless). Maybe because it would raise some linker and compilation unit issues.

That is not actually a big deal and most of the use cases can be resolved using namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

This'll keep you going for the show.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip> // for setprecision(2)
    using namespace std;

    class Call {

    private: double length;

    public:
        // Instantiate and initialize a Call object 
        // using either 
        //   a) the 4-parameter constructor, OR 
        Call(double theLength) 
        {
            this->length = theLength;
        }

        //   b) the default constructor and each of the 
        //      set member functions.
        Call() { }

        void SetLength(double someLength)
        {
            this->length = someLength;
        }

        double GetLength()
        {
            return this->length;
        }
    };

    double costCalc(double costPerMinute, int length)
    {
        Call thisCall(length);
        return thisCall.GetLength()*costPerMinute;
    }

    void callMsg()
    {
        cout << "This is a message about the call" << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int numCalls = 0;
        int length = 0;
        double cost = 0.0;
        double costPerMinute = 0.05;

        // Request the number of calls from the user
        cout << "Enter the number of calls: ";
        cin >> numCalls;

        // Loop for the requested number of calls:
        for (int i = 0; i < numCalls; i++) 
        {
            // Request the user to give you the call length,        
            cout << "Enter length of call " << i << " in minutes: ";
            cin >> length;

            // Get the cost of the call using the calcCallCost
            // function and add it to the total cost of the calls.
            cost += costCalc(costPerMinute, length);


            // Use the callMsg function to print a message about the call 
            callMsg();

        } // end loop


        // Report the total cost of all the calls.
        cout << "Total cost is $" << setprecision(2) << cost << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Compile/run:

```
g++ cost.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
Enter the number of calls: 2
Enter length of call 0 in minutes: 1
This is a message about the call
Enter length of call 1 in minutes: 2
This is a message about the call
Total cost is $0.15
```

Comment: You probably mean `delete`. But is there even a need to use dynamic allocation at all ? Or even a class ?

Comment: The question requires class instantiation (it resembles homework...) and it has rhetorical purpose for the asker.

Comment: I see. I missed that part.

Comment: Added delete(thisCall);